# Can you parse Elasticsearch "q" querystring parameter to NEST object?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am building an API in C# with an ElasticSearch backend. I want consumers to be able to pass filters using the "q" querystring parameter. I don't want to simply pass the filter directly to Elasticsearch because I want to do some validation of the query before sending it.

Is there any way to consume a query such as "?q=date:[2012-01-01 TO 2012-12-31]" and convert it to a QueryContainerDescriptor so that I can perform a search using that criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to do that in Elasticsearch.Net or NEST, but Foundatio has a project, [Foundatio.Parsers](https://github.com/FoundatioFx/Foundatio.Parsers), for parsing Lucene query strings that may be of interest.

Comment: I had been digging around the Elastic docs and the code for a while and didn't see anything. Looks like a Lucene Parser is what I needed. Thanks!